# Find item from EAV based on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

Basically I am trying to build a 'Search by Attribute' function, so a user can choose a field or combination of fields in an EAV database structure e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE `form` (
  `formID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `formName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`formID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `form` (`formID`, `formName`) VALUES
(1, 'A Form');

CREATE TABLE `formFields` (
  `fieldID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `formID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fieldName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fieldID`),
  KEY `formID` (`formID`),
  CONSTRAINT `formFields_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`formID`) REFERENCES `form` (`formID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `formFields` (`fieldID`, `formID`, `fieldName`) VALUES
(1, 1,  'Fruit'),
(2, 1,  'Car Make'),
(3, 1,  'Colour');

CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `itemID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `formID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemID`),
  KEY `formID` (`formID`),
  CONSTRAINT `item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`formID`) REFERENCES `form` (`formID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `item` (`itemID`, `formID`, `notes`) VALUES
(1, 1,  'Some notes....'),
(2, 1,  'don\'t find this one');

CREATE TABLE `itemDetails` (
  `itemID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fieldID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemValue` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `itemID_fieldID` (`itemID`,`fieldID`),
  KEY `fieldID` (`fieldID`),
  CONSTRAINT `itemDetails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`itemID`) REFERENCES `item` (`itemID`),
  CONSTRAINT `itemDetails_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fieldID`) REFERENCES `formFields` (`fieldID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `itemDetails` (`itemID`, `fieldID`, `itemValue`) VALUES
(1, 1,  'apple'),
(1, 2,  'ford'),
(1, 3,  'orange'),
(2, 1,  'banana'),
(2, 2,  'toyota'),
(2, 3,  'blue');

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW item_viewDetails AS
SELECT ff.formID, ff.fieldID, id.itemID, ff.fieldName, id.itemValue
FROM formFields ff
LEFT JOIN itemDetails id ON ff.fieldID = id.fieldID;
```

I have a view set up to return the `itemID`, `formID`, `fieldID`, `fieldName` and `value`. each item will have a minimum number of rows based on how many fields are in the form (the `value` is null if no `itemDetails` record exists)

currently I have a select statement that can search for 1 field eg: `WHERE view.fieldID = X AND view.value = Y

But I would also like to be able to search for multiple fields at the same time in an `AND` fashion. but of course i cannot do `WHERE (view.fieldID = X AND view.value = Y) AND (view.fieldID = A AND view.value = B)` as the details are accross multiple rows with a shared itemID. Is there any way to do this in mysql? or do I have to just `OR` it and then do checking on the application side to discard invalid results?

I have come up with a solution that does work, but I don't know if it is the best as it involves a sub-query with a view.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        COUNT(i.itemID) AS matches,
        ia.*
    FROM item_viewDetails ia
    INNER JOIN item i ON i.itemID = ia.itemID
    WHERE (ia.fieldID = 2 AND ia.itemValue = 'toyota') OR (ia.fieldID = 3 AND ia.itemValue = 'blue')
GROUP BY ia.itemID) AS m
WHERE m.matches = 2;
```

then as I generate the query, I just have to count the number of fields I am trying to match.

Comment: Perhaps the view would be useful

Comment: @Strawberry see the edit.